# What is the norm of this operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Consider the Banach space $B=C[-1,1]$, with $\sup$ norm, for $f\in B$ define $\tilde f(x)=f(|x|)$, $T:B\rightarrow B, T(f)=\tilde f$ we need to show $T$ is a bounded linear operator on $B$, what is $||T||?$

$T(cf+g)= (f+g)(|x|)=cf(|x|)+ g(|x|)=c\tilde f+\tilde g$ so $T$ is linear as we know continous functions over compact set is bounded so clearly $T$ is bounded?

I am not able to determine $||T||$.

Comment: The domain of $T$ is $B$ not $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \|T\| = \sup_{\|f\|_\infty = 1, f \in B} \|Tf\|_\infty = \sup_{\|f\|_\infty = 1, f \in C[0,1]} \|f\|_\infty  = 1$$

Hence $T$ is bounded.

Comment: just to recall myself, $||T||=sup_{||x||=1}||T(x)||$?

Comment: @Flute Well, that is one of [many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm#Equivalent_definitions).